# Capturing nvidia-detect output to list

Tags: python, list, os.system

I want to run nvidia-detect and capture the output in a list or even a string that I can do a string comparison of the output to what I require.
I need to know if the system requires kmod-nvidia or kmod-nvidia-340xx.

I have searched and came up with two possible ways of capturing the output of nvidia-detect.

My initial code was:

```
test=str(os.system('nvidia-detect'))
print test
```

my output is:
kmod-nvida
256

where 256 is the value of test.

So after searching I tried:

```
test2=subprocess.check_output('nvidia-detect', shell=True)
```

and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emmdom/PycharmProjects/mycode/nvidia_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    test2=subprocess.check_output('nvidia-detect')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

Comment: What version of python are you running? `python --version` and could you try running `python -c "import subprocess; print(dir(subprocess))"` to see if you can see the `check_output` function?

Comment: Also, could you post your entire program and how you are running it?

Comment: Hello Scott I am using ver 2.7 on rhel6 I have access to 3.x  if I load the module or use an RHEL7 image but both give me the same error messages and results. The program is not complete this is the first part. I am testing that I can manipulated the output of nvidia-detect. Then I can move forward.

Comment: import os
import subprocess 


test = str(os.system('nvidia-detect'))
print test
test2 = subprocess.check_output('nvida-detect', shell=True)
print test2

Comment: Sorry I could not get the code to format correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work this is what ended up working for me. Thanks

```
import os

os.system('yum -y yum-plugin-nvidia nvidia-detect')
nvidia='kmod-nvidia'
nvidia_340='kmod-nvidia-340xx'

chk_nvidia=(os.popen('nvidia-detect').read()).rstrip()
print chk_nvidia

if chk_nvidia == nvidia:
   print 'nvidia'
   os.system('yum -y kmod-nvidia')

if chk_nvidia == nvidia_340:
    print 'nvidia-340-xxx'
    os.system('yum -y kmod-nvidia-340xx')
```